# attention calculation at matrix level

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pytorch, attention-model

I am confused with the calculation in self attention or attention only.

Lets talk about self-attention first and I have:

```
x -> [batch_size, query_len, embedding_size]
```

now query's shape = key's shape = value's shape in self-attention, so

```
query = key = value = [batch_size, query_len, embedding_size]

self-attention -> softmax((query x key)/ square_root(key_len)) x value
```

In coding, I am confused in which dimension to apply softmax and how to take care of multiplication of score with value ? I mean which dimension is multiplied with each other ?

```
def attention(self, query, key, value):
    N = query.shape[0] # batch size
    # context's shape -> [batch_size, 10, 768]
    query_len, key_len, value_len = query.shape[1], key.shape[1], value.shape[1]

    energy = torch.einsum("nqd,nkd->nqk", [query, key])
    # [b, 10, 768]* [b, 10, 768] -> [b, 10, 10]
    attention = torch.softmax(energy / (self.embed_dim ** (1/2)), dim= 2)

    out = torch.einsum("nql, nld-> nqd", [attention, value])

    return out, attention
```

Comment: lets call s := q/k/v_len, then q * x should produce the score matrix (you called it energy) with shape (s x s), then energy * v should produce again (s x d). And softmax should be applied on the first dimension along the score matrix (which is the second when you consider batch-size). And that's exactly what you have done. So in my understanding your code should be correct. You just could add learnable parameters but I THINK it's correct.

Comment: @TheodorPeifer thank you for your response, and when multiplying attention score(energy in my case) with value I should consider the dimension on which softmax is applied in score, and what dimension or index should I consider from value matrix ?

Comment: hm I dont really understand the question, could you rephrase it? So the multiplication with value comes after softmax so you dont have to think about any softmax dimensions when you do the matrix multiplication with value, if that's what you meant?

Comment: @TheodorPeifer I now understood, thank you for helping me to break it.